# How can I mock ZipFile constructor?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test this code:

```
def read_classes(file):
    if CLASSES in file:
        classes = open(file, "rb").read()
    else:
        with ZipFile(file, "r") as archive:
            classes = archive.read(CLASSES)
    return classes
```

What is important for me is, when the provided file contains `CLASSES` in its name, `open` will be called, otherwise, `ZipFile` will be used. The first part I was able to test already, however, I cannot mock `ZipFile` in order to return a mocked object (`archive`) - which I then can assert that had the `read` method called. This is what I've been trying so far:

```
@patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
def test_givenFile_whenReadClasses_expectArchiveCalled(self, mock_zipfile):
    file = 'sample.file'
    archive = Mock()
    mock_zipfile.return_value = archive

    read_classes(file)

    archive.read.assert_called_once_with("classes.file")
```

When I do that, it continues to execute the original `ZipFile` constructor, giving me: 
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.file'`

Comment: Honest question: why bother?  That function is dead simple.  If you need to test it, check in a pair of files to your project, and write a test which opens each of them and compares them.  One will be a zipped file and one will be a plain file.

Comment: Humm, I known this is possible to be done, but what if I see myself in a more complex code in the future? There must to be a way to mock it right?

Answer (score 2):

Straight to the point:

```
@patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
def test_givenFile_whenReadClasses_expectArchiveCalled(self, mocked_zip_file):
    file = 'file'
    archive = Mock()
    mocked_read = Mock()
    archive.return_value.read = mocked_read
    mocked_zip_file.return_value.__enter__ = archive

    read_classes(dex_file)

    mocked_read.assert_called_once_with('another_file')
```